# Verificação de Acertos Jogo da Forca Python

Tags: python

estou finalizando o jogo da forca em Python. Porém estou com problema na verificação final quando o jogador acerta a palavra, não estou conseguindo criar uma verificação para validar se o jogador acertou a palavra, poderiam me auxiliar?

```
from random import randint

def tentativa1():
    print('''
|─|─────────────────|
| |               (o.o)
| |
| |
| |
| |
| |
| |
|_|=====================
você tem 6 tentativas
========================
''')
def tentativa2():
    print('''
|─|─────────────────|
| |               (o.o)
| |                ||
| |                ||
| |                ||
| |
| |
| |
|_|=====================
você tem 5 tentativas
========================
''')
def tentativa3():
    print('''
|─|─────────────────|
| |               (o.o)
| |                ||_
| |                || \\
| |                ||  \\
| |
| |
| |
|_|=====================
você tem 4 tentativas
========================
''')
def tentativa4():
    print('''
|─|─────────────────|
| |               (o.o)
| |               _||_
| |              / || \\
| |             /  ||  \\
| |
| |
| |
|_|=====================
você tem 3 tentativas
========================
''')
def tentativa5():
    print('''
|─|─────────────────|
| |               (o.o)
| |               _||_
| |              / || \\
| |             /  ||  \\
| |                /
| |              _/
| |
|_|=====================
você tem 2 tentativas
========================
''')
def tentativa6():
    print('''
|─|─────────────────|
| |               (o.o)
| |               _||_
| |              / || \\
| |             /  ||  \\
| |                /\\
| |              _/  \\_
| |
|_|================================
Última Chance !!! Tome cuidado !!!
===================================
''')
def campeao():
    print(''' =-=-=-=-=- PARABÉNS VOCÊ GANHOU !!!! =-=-=-=-=-''')
def final():
    print(''' ========== VOCÊ PERDEU !!! ==========''')

lista_palavras = ["casa", "shopping", "palio", "palmeiras", "lakers", "lucas", "acdc", "dinossauro"]
lista_dicas = ["DICA: Local de descanso...", "DICA: Ir as compras...", "DICA: Carro popular", "DICA: Time sem mundial...", "DICA: Time da NBA...", "DICA: Companheiro de sala conhecido como Nethoes...", "DICA: Banda de Rock...", "DICA: Animal Pré Histórico..."]

print('''====================================
       JOGO DA FORCA - IFPR
====================================''')
print("\n")

print('''====================================
    Pronto para Começar...?
====================================''')
print("\n")

aceita = 1
n_aceita = 0

while True:
    inicio = int(input("Digite (1) para Inicar ou (0) para Sair: "))

    if inicio == 1:

        pos = randint (0, len(lista_palavras)-1)
        palavra = lista_palavras[pos]
        riscos = [" _ "] * len(palavra)

        letras_digitadas = []
        letras_descobertas = []

        print("\n")
        print("Começando o jogo....FORCA - IFPR")

        print("\n")
        print(lista_dicas[pos])
        print("\n")
        print(riscos)
        print("\n")

        erros = 0
        acertos = 0

        while erros < 7 :
            letra = input("Digite uma letra: ").lower()

                if letra in palavra:
                pos = palavra.find(letra)
                for i in range(pos, len(palavra)):
                    if letra == palavra[i]:
                        riscos[i] = letra

            else:
                erros = erros + 1

            if erros == 1:
                tentativa1()
            elif erros == 2:
                tentativa2()
            elif erros == 3:
                tentativa3()
            elif erros == 4:
                tentativa4()
            elif erros == 5:
                tentativa5()
            elif erros == 6:
                tentativa6()
            if erros == 7:
                final()
                break

            print(riscos)

        # Condição para verifcar se a letra já foi digitada.

            if letra in letras_digitadas:
                print("Você já tentou essa Letra. Digite Novamente !!!")

            else:
                letras_digitadas.append(letra)

    else:
        print("Saindo do jogo....")
        print("\n")
        print("Obrigado!")
        break
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uma forma é testar se ainda tem riscos em `riscos`:

```
while erros < 7 :
    if ' _ ' not in riscos:
        print('Voce ganhou')
```

Testando:

```
DICA: Animal Pré Histórico...

[' _ ', ' _ ', ' _ ', ' _ ', ' _ ', ' _ ', ' _ ', ' _ ', ' _ ', ' _ ']
Digite uma letra: d
['d', ' _ ', ' _ ', ' _ ', ' _ ', ' _ ', ' _ ', ' _ ', ' _ ', ' _ ']
Digite uma letra: i
['d', 'i', ' _ ', ' _ ', ' _ ', ' _ ', ' _ ', ' _ ', ' _ ', ' _ ']
Digite uma letra: n
['d', 'i', 'n', ' _ ', ' _ ', ' _ ', ' _ ', ' _ ', ' _ ', ' _ ']
Digite uma letra: o
['d', 'i', 'n', 'o', ' _ ', ' _ ', ' _ ', ' _ ', ' _ ', 'o']
Digite uma letra: s
['d', 'i', 'n', 'o', 's', 's', ' _ ', ' _ ', ' _ ', 'o']
Digite uma letra: a
['d', 'i', 'n', 'o', 's', 's', 'a', ' _ ', ' _ ', 'o']
Digite uma letra: u
['d', 'i', 'n', 'o', 's', 's', 'a', 'u', ' _ ', 'o']
Digite uma letra: r
['d', 'i', 'n', 'o', 's', 's', 'a', 'u', 'r', 'o']
Voce ganhou
```

Comment: No caso da verificação com os riscos, ele vai ficar fora do loop? Porque quando eu coloco esse if dos riscos, assim que eu digito a primeira palavra ele já aparece como Ganhou não completando as outras posições?

Comment: @MayconWillianAlvesdaSilva teria que ser dentro do loop, dentro de `while erros < 7 :`, depois que você já definiu a variável `riscos`

Comment: Sim, eu coloquei mais também não aparece a verificação como Ganhou quando a acerta a palavra.

Comment: @MayconWillianAlvesdaSilva coloquei o local exato do while na pergunta, e também o meu teste - aqui funcionou beleza!

Comment: @MayconWillianAlvesdaSilva como você pode ver na resposta eu coloquei o `if` exatamente embaixo de `while erros < 7:`

Comment: Obrigado! Agora deu certo. Só faltou ele retornar para o menu de opções quando o jogador ganhou.

Comment: @MayconWillianAlvesdaSilva agora que deu certo, poderia marcar minha resposta como aceita, para fechar a pergunta? Só clicar no checkmark verde ao lado da resposta.

Comment: Sim, consegui terminar. Mais como eu faço isso não achei esse checkmark

Comment: @MayconWillianAlvesdaSilva do lado da minha resposta, abaixo dos botões de votação, passa o mouse vai aparecer um V verde, clica nele. [Veja imagem aqui](https://i.imgur.com/ScF4fqF.png)

Answer (score 0):

Se a palavra que o jogador tem de acertar é a variavel `palavra`, e você guarda as letras que ele acertou na lista `riscos` então pode comparar a `palavra` com a conversão em `string` da `lista` utilizando o [`join`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.join).

Logo no código basta colocar:

```
while erros < 7 :
    # (...) o resto do codigo  

    # como ultima instrução do while
    if palavra == ''.join(riscos):
        campeao()
        break
```

Tem muita coisa que pode melhorar e fazer diferente, mas apenas indicando as mais simples:

- Para ficar melhor quando mostra o `riscos` pode utilizar a mesma técnica que na comparação, fazendo `print(' '.join(riscos))`. Repare que utilizei `' '.join` com espaço para os riscos ficarem espaçados.
- Não deve inicializar o `riscos` com espaços ao lado do `_` como fez:

  ```
  riscos = [" _ "] * len(palavra)
  #          ^-^
  ```

  Isso é formatação visual que deve fazer apenas quando vai mostrar para o jogador. Faça antes:

  ```
  riscos = ["_"] * len(palavra)
  ```
- Não crie uma função para cada valor de erros:

  ```
  if erros == 1:
      tentativa1()
  elif erros == 2:
      tentativa2()
  elif erros == 3:
      tentativa3()
  elif erros == 4:
      tentativa4()
  elif erros == 5:
      tentativa5()
  elif erros == 6:
      tentativa6()
  ```

  Em vez disso receba a quantidade de erros na função que mostra o boneco, e desenhe o boneco certo com base nessa quantidade:

  ```
  def tentativa(erros):
      if erros == 1:
          #desenho do 1
  ```

  Isso irá tornar o bloco de `ifs` mostrando anteriormente em:

  ```
  tentativa(erros)
  ```

  Tem até partes do desenho que são iguais em todos os casos, que pode querer reaproveitar e fazer independentemente do número de erros.

Comment: Amigo, eu tentei colocar o def das tentativas conforme vc mostrou porém não consegui, poderia me ajudar?

Comment: @MayconWillianAlvesdaSilva É difícil  de dizer o que quer que seja sem ver como você aplicou. De qualquer forma não convém alterar a pergunta pois descaracteriza as respostas. Se quiser pode deixar um link de um pastebin por exemplo, de como aplicou, ou abrir uma nova pergunta.

Comment: Ok, estou enviando o link do Pastebin para você dar uma olhada: https://pastebin.com/SdynXS5d

Comment: @MayconWillianAlvesdaSilva Isso não foi como eu disse na resposta. Da forma que eu disse você só tem uma função `tentativa` e não `6` funções, e dentro dessa função unica escreve com `print` o que interessa com base em `ifs` sobre uma variável que indique os erros.  E no `main` fica a  apenas `tentativa(erros)` antes de verificação do campeão, nada mais.